# How can I tell which functions have "predefined:" parameters

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to learn d3 and certain functions have paramaters that are passed for them.

For instance this is valid

```
.attr(fill: function(d) {return d.foo})
```

but it also could be written as function(d,i) if an index is to be passed

Similarly in another example from Mike Bostock

```
tick(e)
```

creates another variable that is called later in this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841

I find this confusing because aside from examples I don't know which functions can create variables like d,i and e. I'm sure there is a resource or reasonable explanation so my question is.

How can I learn about these parameters without stumbling upon them in examples?

Comment: [d3 api reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference)

Comment: If I look at the documentation for force.tick() it doesn't mention that it has an internal parameter or not one that I can see?